# Cloudfoundry Sharing Service Instances and user provided service differences

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, cf-bosh

I want to share a DB(PostgreSQL) service across the spaces in same cf Org.

I came across two options

1. User-Provided Service Instances (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html)
2. Sharing Service Instance(https://docs-cloudfoundry-staging.cfapps.io/devguide/services/sharing-instances.html)

The shared service instances say, it improves the security, auditing, and provides a more intuitive user experience.

Can anyone throw some more detailed light on the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 1):

User provided services can do more than be used to share services, sharing services across org/spaces is just one use case for user provided services.

**If you're looking to share services & your service broker supports it, you should use that option over user provided services.**

User provided services are good for cases where the broker doesn't support sharing services or where you want to do something totally different like create a service where no broker exists.

Hope that helps!